# Talmud Yerushalmi M'nukad

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, talmud-yerushalmi

I'm currently looking to buy a Talmud Yerushalmi M'nukad individual/set (not Artscroll/Schottenstein). Are there any out there?

Comment: similar to this http://www.oz-vehadar.com/en/new-products/292

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but according to the Hebrew Wikipedia, [the Steinsaltz Talmud](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%9C%D7%A5) has _Pe'ah_ and _Sheqalim_ of the Yerushalmi, which should be _Menuqad_.

Answer (score 2):

[Heinrich Guggenheimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Guggenheimer)'s translation of and commentary on the Yerushalmi includes a *menuqad* text (although not in *tsurat hadaf*). It can be found [here](https://www.degruyter.com/view/mvw/JERTAL-B?rskey=B8weZX&result=4&q=talmud&tab_body=overview) (and is now on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud/Yerushalmi), if you want to check it out before buying).

Comment: You can also download a PDF here https://www.degruyter.com/serial/jertal-b/html#volumes The print edition also includes a critical apparatus on some volumes, introductions, etc.