# Koren Talmud Yerushalmi [Hardcover]

Tags: jewish-books, talmud-yerushalmi

Does anyone know if this [Talmud Yerushalmi](https://www.judaicaplace.com/koren-talmud-yerushalmi-hardcover/9789653013674/?currency=USD&gclid=CjwKCAjwqpP2BRBTEiwAfpiD--pMYhCnPUZxccfi_2mvTwhocNXziZ9mo_uzh0dAlP6nS1w_mEFPbxoC7QgQAvD_BwE) is Menukad or not?

Comment: Related: "[Talmud Yerushalmi M'nukad](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/114058/1368)".

Comment: This asks for the Koren edition. The question pointed to as duplicate has a different edition in the answer. @Kazibácsi

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,the Koren Talmud Yerushalmi is Menukad.

[image]

https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%92%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A1%D7%98-%D7%A9%D7%A1/%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%93-%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9/

Comment: Is it menukad on the daf side as well?

Comment: That's what I want to know as well

Comment: Is it menukad on the daf side as well?